Broken Pipe every time I try to transfer file from my local to my server using SSH
So I have a Digital Ocean Droplet to which I'm trying to send some files using SCP. However, the Message Authentication Code gets corrupted every few seconds after initiating the transfer. This causes the entire pipe to close and I have to restart the whole upload again. It has happened enough times that I began using SFTP with 'reput file.txt' but since SFTP runs on top of ssh, it has the same issue.
I know it's the MAC because of the auth.log.
I have tried to set the MAC with this option
$ scp -v -o MACs=hmac-md5
But still, it's having the same issue. I have tried generating a new key. Setting the rekey frequency to 1G. Increased the packet sizes allowed by the network interface to mtu 1400. Restarted the service, rebooted the server, and more things I can't remember but I'm still having the same error.
I don't understand where I'm getting this problem. The bandwidth cap is 2Gbps for the droplet so I don't think Digital Ocean is causing any issues.
tradnomic-product-backend.tar                                                                                                18% 1021MB  13.8MB/s   05:14 ETAdebug1: enqueue packet: 94
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: rekeying in progress
debug1: rekeying in progress
debug1: rekeying in progress
debug1: rekeying in progress
debug1: rekeying in progress
debug1: rekeying in progress
debug1: rekeying in progress
debug1: rekeying in progress
debug1: rekeying in progress
debug1: rekeying in progress
debug1: rekeying in progress
debug1: rekeying in progress
debug1: rekeying in progress
debug1: rekeying in progress
debug1: rekeying in progress
debug1: rekeying in progress
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-ed25519
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: rekeying in progress
debug1: rekeying in progress
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY received
debug1: Server host key: ssh-ed25519 SHA256:Vx8Ba5lq1brm4imyytPmfe6623T32vUcAAwXV4+tVeU
debug1: ssh_packet_send2_wrapped: resetting send seqnr 34196
debug1: ssh_set_newkeys: rekeying out, input 176168 bytes 17546 blocks, output 1073642616 bytes 134188080 blocks
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: dequeue packet: 94
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: ssh_packet_read_poll2: resetting read seqnr 8619
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: ssh_set_newkeys: rekeying in, input 176180 bytes 17547 blocks, output 1073675404 bytes 4098 blocks
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
tradnomic-product-backend.tar                                                                                                29% 1608MB  13.7MB/s   04:34 ETAclient_loop: send disconnect: Broken pipe
lost connection

2024-07-28T07:50:30.319460+00:00 droplet-01 sshd[15197]: ssh_dispatch_run_fatal: Connection from user USER x.x.x.x port 53160: message authentication code incorrect

These are the details of the file

It is a docker .tar file containing the layers required to create the image and stuff
It has 5GB inside (I know it's big, not sure why, I'll shrink it later)
It's the only file that fails when using SCP. Other smaller images and files transfer fine without problem.

Am I doing something wrong with scp? Is there a special case for large files?

Your logs show the custom setting being ignored because you're using an AEAD cipher that has a built-in MAC mechanism – but, what makes you think the problem is with the MAC in itself, and not actually the MAC doing its intended job and detecting packet corruption?
